# Working with VC# GUI Forms

Tags: c#

Hi I am a new programmer and i just wannna know that why can't we  close an hide our VC# form with the help of following code -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 frmobj = new Form1();
frmobj.Close();
frmobj.Hide();
}
```

We can do the same thing with the help of following code-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Close();
this.Hide();
}
```

Please tell me why can't we close and Hide the current form with the help of new instance of Form1.

Comment: Why would you want to hide a form, after it has been closed ?

Comment: please tell me as soon as possible...........

Comment: Very unclear question(s)

Comment: Your first sample of code is creating a new form instance then closing it (without having shown it). If there is a child form instance that youve created from a main form you need to use the same reference to close it

Answer (score 3):

Your code is trying to close and hide the *new* form, not the current one.

```
this.Close();
```

means to close the current form.

You can't close the new form before you have even shown it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the Close method, closes and disposes the form, which means that after that method call, the instance of the form does not exists anymore, so, you cannot call any other member-method on that instance, since the instance doesn't exists anymore (is disposed).